# GWT: How can I access its webservice from pure js?

Tags: javascript, gwt

Does anyone have an example of accessing a GWT web service from pure js code?

Part of our site is GWT and part is straight html/css/js.  I need to access the GWT web service from the js side.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to write your GWT application with the required RPC-calls and then make them accessible from your JavaScript with something like this:

```
public MyClass
{

    public static void doRPCCall() { 
        rpcservice.getInstance.doSomething(new AsyncCallback<Void>() {...}   
    }

    public static native void exportStaticMethod() /*-{
       $wnd.doRPCCall =
          $entry(@mypackage.MyClass::doRPCCall());
    }-*/;
}
```

just call the `exportStaticMethod()` at application initialization to assign a variable in the window object called  `doRPCCall`.

[more explanation on JSNI](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html)

Answer (score 2):

Well, compiled GWT is also "straight html/css/js"... If you are looking for a library that will decode the GWT-RPC protocol (I'm assuming you mean that by "GWT web service"), then... just write a small application that will communicate with the webservice using standard Java/GWT interfaces and methods. Export that to a JavaScript library (for example, using [gwt-exporter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/)) that you can use on your site.